# Storing data for a python application

Tags: python, backup

I am making a little program that will backup some files from a game to some site like dropbox, but instead of adding every single one of the games I want to backup by hand . I would like to make a small wizard that would append information on were the game's files are to something.

For example , say that I wanted to backup a game like minecraft. I want the wizard to ask information like the executable for the game ,an optional icon, and the types of information to back up.When the program starts up  for the first time I would want it to give a user a search box to look up games, then the program would check to see if it exist , and provide a nice interface with check boxes and things to select things you want to do .

I am basically asking if there is some kind of database for storing information , and that information should should be copied from a single database. However, when some one downloads my program and adds the games they have to the list, it should copy over that information from the single database .

I am sorry if I am horrible at explaining things :/

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please try narrowing it down to a specific question.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a database to store information , and for each user of the program it would create a local database that only contains information needed that it would copy from a larger database .

Comment: You could a) use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to store serialized Python objects b) use a database like [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) to store the information, which could also be distributed or c) come up with your own format for storing the information related to your program. Without more information we couldn't possibly say which of them is the best choice.

Comment: thumbs up for pickle for small scale data persistence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use sqlite3 and just store userdata with the name
http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

```
 import sqlite3
 db = sqlite3.connect("settings.db")
 c = db.cursor()
 c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdata (
                    user_name TEXT,
                    settings1 TEXT,
                    settings2 TEXT
                    );""")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO user_data (user_name,settings1,settings2) VALUES (?,?,?)",("bob","some_Value","some Other Value")
 db.commit()  #save it
 c.execute("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user_name=?",GetUserName())
 print c.fetchall()
```

or use pickle http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

```
 import pickle
 try:
     with open("settings.dat") as f:
         print pickle.load(f)
 except IOError:
      print "No Settings Found"
 user_data = {"bob":{"path1":"some/path","otherVar":"56"},
              "paul":{"url":"http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html"}
              }
 with open("settings.dat","wb") as f: 
       pickle.dump(f)
```

both of these are untested by me ... they are just off the top of my head and may contain minor errors

Comment: Thank you :D , I never thought of using pickle that way .